# Need to return sysdate and past 9 dates

Tags: sql, oracle

With the code below I can return this month and past 6 months.
My code:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(TRUNC(to_date( sysdate),'Month'), -rownum+1), 'Month') mon,
      rownum month_order
FROM dual
CONNECT BY rownum <=
  (SELECT COUNT(mon)
   FROM
       (SELECT TO_CHAR( add_months( start_date, level-1 ), 'fmMonth' ) AS mon
        FROM
          (SELECT to_date( add_months(TRUNC(sysdate),-6)) start_date,
            to_date( sysdate) end_date
          FROM dual)
          CONNECT BY level <= months_between( TRUNC(end_date,'MM'), TRUNC(start_date,'MM') ) + 1) dual);
```

In the same way I have to return this date and past 9 dates.
Please help me on this to return 10 dates by using `connect by`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query for the last ten days.

```
 select sysdate - (level-1)
        , level as day_order
 from dual
 connect by level <= 10;
```

Your month query seems extremely over-engineered. This would do the same thing:

```
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 - level), 'Month')
       , level as month_order
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

---

> "Let suppose if the data is available on today's date and remaining 9 date's doesn't have any data but it has to display the count as zero"

Use the generated result set in an outer join:

```
with q as (
 select sysdate - (level-1) as dt
        , level as day_order
 from dual
 connect by level <= 10 
)
select q.dt as txn_date
      , sum(t42.col1)
from q
     left outer join t42
      on t42.transaction_date = q.dt
group by q.dt;
```

Comment: Let suppose if the data is available on today's date and remaining 9 date's doesn't have any data but it has to display the count as zero

Comment: Why can't you? hint `trunc(remedy_created_on) = q.dt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT ( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 1 ) - ROWNUM
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the same way i have to return this date and past 9 dates.

This will get today and the past 9 days:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - LEVEL + 1 AS day
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

> this month and past 6 months

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 - LEVEL ), 'Month' ) AS month
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
```